# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError GCOverhead Limit Exceeded Error

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, garbage-collection

I have a java spring application running on AWS C4.Large (4 Gb Memory) with Apache Tomcat 8. Am getting java.lang.OutOfMemoryError GCOverhead Limit Exceeded Error while instantiating a bean of 30000 records during server startup.

`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [java.lang.String]: Factory method 'loadBeanMaps' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`

But my `free -m` output then,

`total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3765       1706       2059          0         29        446
-/+ buffers/cache:       1230       2534
Swap:            0          0          0`

Would like to know how to view the limit which was set? Is it percentage based on server capacity. Because when I change my server to m4.large ( 8 Gb Memory Server ) am not getting this error. How to view this limit? And how to handle this error?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to check the JVM options for your process

Use following command to get the details of all running Java processes

```
jps -mlvV
```

`jps` comes with the `Jdk` installation, it should be in the `jdk/bin`

This will give you output like following

```
10780  -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7 -Xms40m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xverify:none -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.IEVersion=10001 -Xmx1200m -javaagent:lombok.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Identify the process for your java app and look the values in `Xmx` arguments

Answer (score 0):

ok, the first this to look here is if your application have any memory leak. you can see the class histogram to check any memory leak. you can use jcmd utility for this.

If this is on linux like OS than you can check the memory argument simple grepping the tomcat process.

```
ps -ef | grep tomcat
```

By default the JVM is configured to throw this error if you are spending more than 98% of the total time in GC and after the GC less than 2% of the heap is recovered.

From my personal experience increasing the heap size a bit solves the issue provided its not a memory leak.